# Visualising a standard multiple regression

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, spss, scatterplot

I am running a standard multiple regression for my research project. I have 4 predictor variables trying to predict one outcome variable. I've run the analysis in SPSS but Im not sure how I can visualise the data in a graph/scatterplot. I have two significant relationships of predictors with the outcome variable and I intend to visualise this so I can discuss the correlations. I've come across matrix scatterplots, but in SPSS i struggle to see how I would interpret it and find it to be unclear. Im not necessarily interested in how the predictor variables interact or affect each other, only creating a visualisation of how they respectively predict the outcome variable. Im stuck, and my only options at the moment are:

1. doing it like this:

[image]

2. trying a matrix scatterplot (not sure due to the fact im not directly interested in relationships between predictors).
3. trying to put all 4 predictors on x and dependent variable on y. (see below)
   [image]
4. a graph of  a standardised predicted value and standardised residual (although i dont really understand this) see below:

[image]

I'd really appreciate any help! Ideally an option that is nice to discuss and evaluate in a thesis project, and that clearly visualises the data.

Comment: I think we need more information about your situation and your data to make sense of this & provide useful advice.